# Is this whats meant?

Tags: grammar

May be we are not such fools as we look. But though we be, we are well content, so long as we may be two fools together.\

Does this mean

"It may be that we are not as foolish as we look. But even if we are, we are OK as long as we are both foolish"???

Answer (score 1):

the quote from R.D. Blackmore in *Lorna Doone* broken down is

> Maybe we are not such fools as we look.
>   *perhaps we are not as foolish as we look*
>
> But though we be
>   *but even if we are*
>
> we are well content
>   *we are very happy*
>
> so long as we may be two fools together.
>   *as long as we can be fools together*.

Meaning *foolishness* like misery, enjoys company.